# What's causing the number of utxos to increase so quickly?

Tags: utxo, decentralization, utxo-set

I was using `gettxoutsetinfo` a couple weeks ago (maybe a bit longer, can't remember) and the total number of txouts was something like 115 million. Now it's sitting at around 124 million.

What's up with the super fast increase here? Any concerns with how much RAM the utxo set will use in the near future if this rate of increase is here to stay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **What's causing the number of utxos to increase so quickly?**

An old [article at Yahoo finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/news/bitcoin-utxos-close-time-high-140117417.html) pointed out

> the UTXO count of bitcoin (BTC) is ticking upwards

...

> UTXOs also tells us that despite a new, large cohort of people interacting with bitcoin thanks to **Ordinals**,

That reinforces my feeling that, although the payload of Ordinals Inscriptions are not in the UTXO data, they do cause a great number of UTXOs to be created with tiny Bitcoin values. I think this is especially true with BRC-20 usage. It seems people create large numbers of tiny-valued UTXOs as preparation for recording BRC-20 actions.

Comment: Any concerns with RAM? Am I right in saying it's important for mining that the utxo set doesn't take up too much memory? Last time I checked I think gettxoutsetinfo was showing close to 9 GB. RAM should continue to get cheaper over time but maybe not fast enough. I know Utreexo is being considered as well